# Why does my media queries not work even when it is written correctly

Tags: html, css, laravel-5

I am trying to set the media queries in my footer class but for some reason its not working.

Am running the server with Laravel 5 but am not sure that's what is causing this.

[image: The image shows the HTML, CSS and the phone screen. Note that the screen width of the phone is above 450px, therefore the footer color should have turned red.]

Here are the codes:

**HTML & CSS**

```css
.footer{
    background-color:rgba(40, 50, 60, 1);
    height: 200px;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */

/* if screen width goes above 450px do this */
@media only screen and(min-width: 450px)
{
    /* make the color red */
    .footer{
        background-color: red!important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer d-flex justify-content-center">
  <span class="font-md text-light">Footer</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes it is solved thanks to you. Next time I will add space between the "and" and "(min-width: 450px)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add space between `and` and the `(` like this `and (min-width: 450px)`.

If you don't set a space, it will not set any code as it will bewrong grammar.

### DEMO

```css
.footer{
    background-color:rgba(40, 50, 60, 1);
    height: 200px;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */

/* if screen width goes above 450px do this */
@media only screen and (min-width: 450px)
{
    /* make the color red */
    .footer{
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer d-flex justify-content-center">
  <span class="font-md text-light">Footer</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr MaxiGui. You helped me fix the problem. It was the '''and(min-width:" that caused the problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your HTML `<head>` element:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And your media queries should look like this (not the "**only screen and**").

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 577px) {
    /* Your responsive classes */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 578px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* Your responsive classes */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* Your responsive classes */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  /* make the color red */
    .footer{
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}
```

use this code you will get result.

Comment: Answers which simply say "use this" do not help educate the asker about what they're doing wrong. What does your code do to fix the problem? Why does omitting the screen restriction work? What if the user _does_ want to target screen as well?